# How to fill a variable

Tags: variables, robotframework

what random value can be passed to variable `${ISOBOX_PHONE_01.imsi}` to resolve it without an error.

I don't need the variable but also not able to ignore and my script fails.So, I just need a random value for this variable to pass.what random value can be passed to variable `${ISOBOX_PHONE_01.imsi}` to resolve it without an error?

Comment: setting variables is well documented in the robot framework user guide. Have you looked there for answers?

Answer (score 1):

If the value of the variable does not matter, then setting the variable is the quickest way to resolve dependency:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Set Variable Test Case
    ${ISOBOX_PHONE_01.imsi}=    Set Variable    SomeRandomTextValue
```

However, if the dependency is more complex, then it will require more information.